# D3.js Bar Chart axis label having select box

Tags: drop-down-menu, d3.js, nvd3.js

We have requirement to add drop down with axis label so that user can change the data from there.We require this drop down box effect on only specific label.

One approach we have tried is to add svg:image with label and the functionality is working fine but the other label is having the down arrow image that is not required. So can anybody help me out how I can select only one label? Actually there are multiple labels and its index is getting changed on chart update. Please find below code which is working for adding images to all labels.

e.g.

```
g.selectAll('.nv-x.nv-axis').selectAll('.tick.major').append("svg:image").
on("click", click)
.attr("xlink:href", "images/top-bar-logo.png")
.attr("width", 20)
.attr("height", 20).attr("x", -20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`filter()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) to select the ticks that you need to append the image to. The documentation I've linked to has a few examples -- you might be able to do it without `filter()` by passing a different selector to `selectAll()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lars!!! My requirement is fulfilled with the solution you have suggested. :)